# Graphql react imprimir keys de un objeto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, objeto, graphql

Hola estoy trabajando con react y Graphql y para la query mi intension es usar un objeto que contiene las query.

este es mi codigo el "obj" es donde estan todas las llaves:

```
const {isLoading,isError,data}=useQuery([`gridData-${grid.codigo}-${grid.paraEstado}`, {page,size}],
    () => request(
            endpoint,
            gql`
                query{
                    ${grid.codigo}(${grid.paraEstado ?'estado: '+grid.paraEstado+',' :''} ${perfil ? 'perfil: '+perfil+',':''} area: ${area}, page: ${page},size: ${size}){
                        ${obj}
                    }
                }
            `
        ).then(({data}) => data),
        {onSuccess: (data) => {setResultado({
            rows: data.content,
            rowCount: data.total
        })}}
)
```

hice un console log para ver como esque se estaba imprimiendo y se hacia de esta esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no quiero que se imprima de esa forma, si no que se imprima su contenido que es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me parece que debes tener una interface tipo GraphQL playground en donde puedes escribir las query y ver sus resultados, si es asi ¿Podrías compartir el query que escribes en dicha interface?